# ansible if else construction

Tags: bash, ansible

Recently I started to get acquainted with ansible.
Kick me in the right direction on such a task. It is necessary to use ansible to repeat the script on the bash, which in turn processes several if else loops, this script also uses the variables inside which the commands are executed.
**Which construct should I use to recreate the if else loops in an ansible playbook?**
Let me give you an example.
Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

```
file1=$(cat /root/md_sum/00-system.conf.bak)
file2=$(cat /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf)
file_time2=$(date -r /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf)
date_audit2=$(date -r /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf +%H:%M:%S)
audit_key=config_kernel_activ


#check audit
if [[ $(auditctl -l) = *"-w /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf -p rwa"* ]];
then
echo "audit up"
else
echo "audit down";auditctl -w /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf -p war -k $audit_key
fi


#check sum
if (ls -A /root/md_sum/00-system.md5);
then
echo "sum up"
else
echo "sum down";md5sum /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf > /root/md_sum/00-system.md5
fi


#check bak file
if (ls -A /root/md_sum/00-system.conf.bak);
then
echo "bak files are present"
else
echo "bak files are not present";cp /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf /root/md_sum/00-system.conf.bak
fi


#if sum was change/else compare
if [[ $(md5sum -c /root/md_sum/00-system.md5) = *OK* ]];
then
echo "files have not changed"
else
echo "files has changed "$file_time2;echo "CHANGES 00-system.conf ";comm -31 <(tr ' ' $'\n' <<< $file1 | sort) <(tr ' ' $'\n' <<< $file2 | sort);echo "more details ";ausearch -k $audit_key -i | grep $date_audit2 | grep "ouid"
fi
```

Comment: What is the question? And what is the desired output? Please refine the question so we can answer it properly.

Comment: And the condition in your check sum command looks unncessary convoluted. Why do you create a subshell? You could achieve the same effect with `if [[ -e /root/md_sum/00-system.md5 ]]; ...`.

Comment: @KevinC thanks for the answer.
I need ansible to do what a bash script does, excluding passing the script or storing it on the server.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for the comment, I will take it into account!

Answer (score 0):

Ansible doesn't have an "else" option. It only knows the "when"-condition. If condition does not match, Ansible ignores the task. So an easy example is

```
- name: "Get state of file"
  stat:
    path: "/root/md_sum/00-system.conf.bak"
  register: file_state

- name: "File exists"
  debug:
    msg: "File exists"
  when:
    - "file_state.stat.exists"

- name: "File doesn't exist"
  debug:
    msg: "File doesn't exists"
  when:
    - "not file_state.stat.exists"
```